# Excel: How to do search from range of column and match to substring of row?

Tags: excel-formula

I have 2 tables here. On first table, I would like to flag 'Partial Validated' (column A) to "Done" when the 2nd table (column F) flagged to YES for the find_item.

The 'Find Item' column can be any substring of column B. How to achieve this?

#### 1st Table

```
COLUMN A              COLUMN B
Partial validated     List
==================    =================================
<Done>                Apple, Orange, Banana, watermelon
                      Apple, watermelon
<Done>                Mango
                      Banana, Tomato
<Done>                Orange, Apple
```

#### 2nd Table

```
COLUMN E       COLUMN F
find_item      validated
===========    =========
Orange         YES
watermelon     NO
Mango          YES
Apple          NO
```

Appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, for the best performance you have to use macros. Formulas aone cant handle those operations in that sceme.
Ifyou cannot use macros, you'll have to pivot 2. table to this:

note: replace ; with , in formulas as it depends on your regional settings

```
ORANGE  Watermelon  Mango   APPLE
YES     NO          YES     NO
```

and separate comma data in 1st table to this

```
Column B        column C column D Column E
Apple(Cell B2)  Orange  Banana  Watermelon
Apple           Watermelon      
Mango           
Banana          Tomato      
Orange          APPLE
```

then count the YES & occurences of given item from table 1

```
ORANGE(Cell G1) Watermelon  Mango   APPLE
YES             NO          YES     NO
1(x)            0           0       0
0               0           0       0
0               0           1       0
0               0           0       0
1               0           0       0
```

code of cell marked with (x) :

```
=IFERROR(IF(HLOOKUP(G$1;$B3:$E3;1;FALSE)>0;IF(G$2="YES";1;0);0);0)
```

then finally put this down to cell A2 and drag down

```
 =IF(SUM(G3:J3)>0;"DONE";"")
```

this will create the desired action, whenever yo change the value YES of a given item to some other value, the total unit count will change and if unit total in a given row is equal to 0 "done" will change to zero